# getChildFragmentManager() from Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, fragmentmanager

In my application I have a fragment class whose activity class is `AppCompatActivity` and in particular fragment I have a `ViewPager` and I want to inflate using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` inner class.

**Adapter Class:**

```
 private class SliderAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
        List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> frags;
        Context ctx;

        public SliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> frags, Context ctx) {
            super(fm);
            this.frags = frags;
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return frags.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return frags.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) container.inflate(ctx,R.layout.news_pager_layout,null);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.slidr_img);
            TextView catTxt = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.catTxt);
            TextView titleText = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.slider_text);
            TextView viewCount = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.view_count);
            ((ViewPager)container).addView(rl);
            return rl;
        }
    }
```

Now I am trying to pass `FragmentManager` to it from my fragment class containing the ViewPager but I am getting error of incompatible parameters

```
SliderAdapter adp = new SliderAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getSupportFragmentManager()
SliderAdapter adp = new SliderAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), list);